# PHP password_hash function value isn't same for each string

Tags: php, password-hash, php-password-hash

I'm try to hash user password with using ***password_hash()*** PHP function.But,it function is work hashing,not constant.

```
<?php 
    echo password_hash('a',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array(
            'cost' => 12
         ));
?>
```

### Result for 4th testing time

```
1. $2y$12$SRmipqM7AsYkx3Xc8QGHNex69rGXeVyWGTYrh9T8sh1cP3UrdjfQi
2. $2y$12$zx.GUgtcake3wMfl3/YXXeG1.8mmHKyRruL3nWj8OmA.RbEYqeW6u
3. $2y$12$XQtmFplcehkgWLbGrOUsNOlXDU/NGrwZlt3HM88hLbUHXhjXNF4km
4. $2y$12$q9/OSZdDJw7af4Hw4MGlHeY7UMtWr9/Cj0nj/N6PaoilNoUBePt7O
```

Comment: What do you expect? That it would be constant ?

Comment: Everytime you use `password_hash()` without the **salt** it will generate a random salt, which means your password would not be constant.

as `password_hash()` generates the hash and the hash is basicly salt + hash

`password_verify()` method expects the password and the hashed password
the password [param 1] will be hashed using the salt from the hashed password, if it equals it returns true, else it fails :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As some suggested to use MD5, Do not use it for password hashing.

Well now to answer your question `how to check a password matches`

`Password_Hash()` is to generate a password hash, which will create a random salt with it, this hash will be used upon hashing.
your end result would be: salt+hash, **however** you can give it a `salt` with this method in it's options but let's keep it that it does it by itselves.

`Password_Verify()` uses a parameter for the password and one for the hashed password.
as I said earlier the hashed password is salt+hash
which makes sense that `Password_Verify()` only need these and not an additional called `salt`

So what happens with `Password_Verify()` is that it takes out the salt and use `Password_Hash()` with that salt.
then check if the received hash equals the given hash.
if it matched then it's true, else it's false.

[Password_Hash() Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

[Password_Verify() Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

---

**Update 18-04-2018 (d-m-Y)**

> **WARNING**
>
> The salt option has been **deprecated** as of **PHP 7.0.0**.
>
> It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

[More information about Salting - SO Answer below by Veve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626635/3504247)

[Why not to use MD5 for Password Hashing - PHP FaQ Answer](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

[Why not to use MD5 for Password Hashing - SO Answer by: Silverlightfox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502701/3504247)

Comment: No problem and remember, if it helped don't forget to accept the answer :-)
I would also definitaly say: Just use the methods given. the salt generated is perfectly fine, use the `password_hash()` with `password_verify()`

Comment: I really understand `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` . Thank you @MikeM . I'm too late for accept for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `password_hash()` and get constants hashes (not sure of the plural...), **add a salt** when using it. (but don't, see the **caution** below)

As [explained in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), if you don't, the salt will be randomly generated each time you use the function, and as a result the generated hash won't be constant.

```
<?php 
    echo password_hash('a',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array(
            'salt' => $salt_defined_for_the_user,
            'cost' => 12,
         ));
?>
```

About the salt you should use, here is a good explaination of [wmfrancia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630704/wmfrancia) extracted [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22966549/4074148):

> SALTING
>
> Passwords should always be salted before hashed. Salting adds a random
>   string to the password so similar passwords don't appear the same in
>   the DB. However if the salt is not unique to each user (ie: you use a
>   hard coded salt) than you pretty much have made your salt worthless.
>   Because once an attacker figures out one password salt he has the salt
>   for all of them.
>
> When you create a salt make sure it is unique to the password it is
>   salting, then store both the completed hash and salt in your DB. What
>   this will do is make it so that an attacker will have to individually
>   crack each salt and hash before they can gain access. This means a lot
>   more work and time for the attacker.

---

## Caution: you should'nt try to get constants hashes with your own salt

I'm simply responding here to your willing to have constant hashes, but as said by [halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) and [martinstoeckli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575765/martinstoeckli) in the comments, and also noted in the official doc,

> > **Caution** It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically
> >     for you if you do not specify one.

.

> You really should *not* create your own salt, the function tries its
>   best to create a safe and random one. When you store a user specific
>   salt as your example shows, you do the same as password_hash() does
>   anyway. It includes the salt in the hash-value so the function
>   password_verify() can pick it up from there

[Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3504247/mike-m) has a detailed description for [the use of `password_verify()` instead in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626886/4074148).

Comment: **$salt_defined _for_the_user** is just need minimum 22 character.
:P :)

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing, I suggest using the default salt capabilities of this function.

Comment: You really should _not_ create your own salt, the function tries its best to create a safe and random one. When you store a user specific salt as your example shows, you do the same as `password_hash()` does anyway. It includes the salt in the hash-value so the function `password_verify()` can pick it up from there.

Comment: I don't say he has to create a salt, I'm simply answering his question about getting constant hashes. I'll add your warning to my answer.

Comment: Veve check my answer I explained it in details, there is also a warning under the first examples under Note starting with **CAUTION** in the Password_Hash() doc

Comment: Again, totally agree with you, hence the added notice, that I'll make more proiminent with link to your answer :) I can quote it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by the older methods that produce the same hash no matter how many times you try.

Eg MD5 () would five you the same hash for the same password all the time..

Password_hash gives you different string all the time as it contains a different salt each tim you run it.

When you retrieve the hash password from the database (eg based on the email the user provided)
Password_verify will will read the whole string which is salt+pass together, will use the first characters which is the salt and will use this salt with the plain password the user provided to encrypt it.

Then it will compare the result with the remaining of the salt+hash that was pulled from the database (the remaining now should be the hash.. without the salt).

I hope this helped tou understand why tou get different strings all the time tou use password hash for the same password.