# how to hash password on client side? how to transmit password from java device(android)?

Tags: java, security, hash, md5

we have not clear text of password on our server and we want to hash what user entered on the app and then send it to server.(we send it over https)

we have md5(passwrod) without salting on server but ASAP we change it to md5(password+salt) or md5(md5(password)+salt) if it is secure!
i read this question:
[Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715920/about-password-hashing-system-on-client-side)

but there was a problem. this is not secure if server send salt to app because of this article below "In a Web Application, always hash on the server" title
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

so if i send md5(password+random bit) + random bit to server. server can't recognize is password true or not! because server only have hash of passwords!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 is never secure for password hashing ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496061/why-not-use-md5-for-password-hashing)). Instead, I recommend using the [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) algorithm.
It's indeed a good idea to perform the hashing operation server-side, so you should rely on security at the transport layer, e.g. use [SSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html) rather than TCP (or HTTPS, as you are already doing).

Comment: is it ok to use bcrypt(salt+md5(password)) in our server then i send md5(password) to server.or bcrypt(salt+bcrypt(password)) ?! the hashing security article believe this is not secure! The WRONG Way: Double Hashing & Wacky Hash Functions!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you store the authentication hash serverside and you match that with the hash generated clientside from the user's inputted password. Obtain the original hash from the signin form. Post some code if you need more specific assistance. Hope that helps.