# PHP: Validate Current Password

Tags: php

Hi guys I am implementing a password validation in my project.

Validate Current password in order to change a new password..

here is my query:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$pass = $userRow['password'];

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $id = $_SESSION['user'];
        $new_pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_pass']));
        if($_POST['old_pass'] != $pass){
            ?>
                <script>alert('Wrong Old Password');</script>
             <?php
        }else if(mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$new_pass' WHERE id=$id")){
             ?>
                <script>alert('Password Successfully Updated');</script>
             <?php
         }else{
             ?>
               <script>alert('Failed');</script>
             <?php
         }
    }
```

the alert "Wrong Old Password" always popping out even though I entered the correct old password. so how to fix this?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: what is the question? what is the problem?

Comment: 1. Don't use `mysql_`. 2. Don't use `md5` for passwords. 3. What's the question?

Comment: Also, md5 and no salt is about the worse you can use for storing passwords. You might as well store the passwords as plain text. Search for PBKDF2 instead.

Comment: Specify your question properly

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Even with a salt `md5` is outdated

Comment: sorry I accidentally click post question

Comment: @DarkBee I know, that's why I added *and no salt* instead of *without salt*, but to make it clear, I've added PBKDF2.

Comment: Are you saving the old password as md5 ? .. if so, you cannot equal the old pass (which is not yet md5 encrypted) with the retrieved pass from database which is md5 encrypted

Comment: then edit your question before you get any more negative votes.

Comment: @DTH Oh yeah, I got the Idea now

Comment: Nice tell me if it worked .. i'd be pleased to post that as my answer for your accept ;)

Comment: @DTH Great!! it works sir :) thanks..

Comment: greate .. i have posted my answer for your accept .. with a little side note .. bare in mind that you CAN used md5, depends on the level of ambition for your project. If you aim for security (and not just some home fiddle work for fun) read the linked post :)

Comment: I'll stick in using the md5 sir, :) because the project that I am doing is for demo only as an example of encrypted password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saving the old password as md5 ? .. if so, you cannot equal the old pass (which is not yet md5 encrypted) with the retrieved pass from database which is md5 encrypted

PLease also as a side note look at this thread explaining why not to use md5

[Why not to use MD5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496061/why-not-use-md5-for-password-hashing)

Answer (score 0):

Your old password was stored in encrypted format. Try this:

```
f(md5($_POST['old_pass']) != $pass)
```