# PHP | issue with " & '

Tags: php

I have just started up with few tutorials on PHP, the problem I often get with is " & '

following is the code where the issue is,

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]).'", "'.md5(md5($_POST["email"]).$_POST["password"])'")';
```

This query simply takes inputs from the form fields, namely Email & Password & inserts into the database.

Can someone please help me where I am going wrong & any tips so that in future I dont commit any such mistakes?

Thanks...

Comment: Please take into account that we cannot read your mind or peek your monitor over your shoulder. Your code does not have any `&` character. What problem do you have?

Comment: BTW, you should find a tutorial that uses prepared statements. Having to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` manually is so annoying.

Comment: Tutorials which learn you such ways of executing queries should be thrown off.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález he is using `&` to mean AND. His problem is with `"` and `'`, single and double quotes

Comment: You should never use `md5()` for password hashing. If you're using php 5.5+, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: @bassxzero How can you know that? Can *you* look at this screen? ;-)

Comment: Since the other answers are wrong. Your problem is that you're missing a `.` (concatenation) after `$_POST["password"])`. As for tips, use prepared queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález bass notified u the problem

Comment: @bassxzero thanks for all ur help buddy, apparently the problem wasn't with the single & double quotes :)

Comment: "bass notified u the problem" - Sorry, I'm slightly lost. Is he a co-worker or someone you know in real life? Otherwise he has no way to know that because the code you've shared does not have any attempt to use `&`, `AND` or any other boolean operator :-?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`prepare`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [**`bind`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) statement to escape such type of character and prevent from sql injection

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES(?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["email"], md5(md5($_POST["email"]) . $_POST["password"]));

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Read [Why not use MD5 for password hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496061/why-not-use-md5-for-password-hashing)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

In MySQL, Strings (VARCHARs) are surrended with single quotes (ie `'`). You are using double quotes `"` arround your values. That's why you gave an error.

## Explanation

If we take your `$query` and we replace calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `md5` with values `foo` and `bar` just to see what happens PHP replaces with the real values; the resulting string would be:

```
'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("'. 'foo' .'", "' . 'bar'. '")'
```

which gives after concatenations

```
'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("foo", "bar")'
```

You can clearly see that values are using `"` which will not work in MySQL.

## Solution

The solution would be si,ply to use `'` for values. This can be done in two ways:

**Using `"` for the whole string and `'` inside for values**

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('foo', 'bar')"
```

which gives

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"])."', '".md5(md5($_POST["email"]).$_POST["password"])"')";
```

**Using `'` for the whole string and escaping the `'` of values using `\`**

```
'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES(\'foo\', \'bar\')'
```

which gives

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES(\''.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]).'\', \''.md5(md5($_POST["email"]).$_POST["password"])'\')';
```

## Important Notes

- **Never inject PHP variables into an SQL query like this, use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead**
- **Never use `md5` to hash passwords, use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php) instead**

Comment: Regarding `password_hash()`, if you're using PHP < 5.5 but > 5.3.7, you can use the [password-compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: thanks @webNeat for taking out time for an effective explanation. i shall certainly use you advice, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

this will work.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[\"email\"]).'", "'.md5(md5($_POST[\"email\"]).$_POST[\"password\"])'")';
```

Comment: And in this case, it's actually wrong since the `$_POST` variable isn't inside any double quotes.

Comment: using forward slash ( \ ) u can escape the special characters. refere this link furthermore http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` only make string storable in mysql preventing danger characters you also need to filter variables for xss also you can use `htmlentities` function to convert html special chars..for above purpose.

also instead nesting all var directly you can first load them into variables..

ex.

```
$email=$_POST['email'];


$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($email, $_POST["email"]);
$password='value';
```

now

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("$email","$password")';
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the ACTUAL problem

Answer (score -1):

You didnt add dot(.) after password let it check.
I hope this is useful for you. Either of these should work its just a matter of your preference.

Possible answer #1

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]);
$pwd = md5(md5($_POST["email"]).$_POST["password"]);

$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("'.$email.'", "'.
$pwd.'")';
```

Possible answer #2

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]).'", "'.md5(md5($_POST["email"]).$_POST["password"]).'")';
```

Comment: How about an explanation and some formatting. I hardly understand what you're trying to convey and I'm not new to the language like he is.

Comment: I changed your formatting a little more and added some detail. Go check it out